# Controller xxx is not a function 'undefined in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Just starting to learn Angular.  I am copying an example line for line from an O'Reilly book and am getting the message that the Cart Controller is not a function.  I really cant see what I am doing wrong in the example below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <title>AngularJS Tutorials</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"></link>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myscripts.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-controller='CartController'>

  <div>
        <h1>
            Your Shopping Cart
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <span>{{item.title}}</span>
        <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
        <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
        <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
        <button ng-click='remove($index)'>Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

myscripts.js is as below:

```
function CartController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {title: 'paint pot', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
        {title: 'paint brush', quantity: 12, price: 2.66}
    ]

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
        $scope.items.splice($index);
    }
}
```

myscripts.js is being located correctly according to chrome network console.  But I get the same message when I place the script for the controller on the html page also.

Comment: not sure if it's related, but you have more closing `div`s than opening `div`s

Comment: thanks for spotting, although this isn't causing this particular issue.  I updated 'quantiry' to 'quantity' in the array defintion in the text above since original post, not that this was the issue - but it breaks the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was missing a semi colon after my data array definition, $scope.items....

Working now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got this code working.

First I added this line at the top of the script.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

This registers the app with angular.

Next I changed around the controller a little by registering it with myApp like so:

```
myApp.controller('CartController', function($scope){    
    $scope.items = [
        {title: 'paint pot', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
        {title: 'paint brush', quantiry: 12, price: 2.66}
    ]

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
        $scope.items.splice($index);
    }
});
```

Then I did this with the HTML

```
<html lang="en"  ng-app="myApp">
```

Here is the working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7chQ93n9KsWYCxHQbqJf?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for this, although it works for me as per my last post - just by adding a semi-colon to the end of the array definition $scope.items.

Comment: I saw that right after posting this. I don't know why my plunk is working without that change. Oh well. Good luck learning Angular. It is a fun library.